# ROS_Environments for Hector_SLAM

Tags: slam, navigation, rosws, hector-slam, best-practices

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm in the process of learning ROS with a specific target of using Hector_SLAM. I'm using rosws and have made workspaces, directories, etc. I am now exploring Hector_SLAM with its multiple stacks and I am wondering a best protocol either:

A) making a unique workspace for Hector_SLAM
B) using an existing workspace but making a unique dirctory

Etc.

I would appreciate some thoughts here.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/40035/ros_environments-for-hector_slam/) by [TJump](https://answers.ros.org/users/2785/tjump/) on ROS Answers with karma: 160 on 2012-07-27

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can do whatever fits your work-flow. For many people the simplicity of a single workspace is best.

I use multiple workspaces, because I maintain packages on several ROS distros. Never mix distros within a single workspace.

It is better to open a new shell when you need to switch workspaces.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2012-07-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [TJump](https://answers.ros.org/users/2785/tjump/) on 2012-07-28**:
Thanks for the input. I can see where multiple workspaces across different distros would be a great approach. I'm still trying to work out if projects with many stacks would be better serviced if kept in their own workspace or just within a dedicated directory within a shared workspace. Cheers!

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-07-28**:
When using tools like `rosws`, I would keep each workspace flat.